# Where does device mode and state output come from, and how do I disable it?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, shell, hostapd

Whenever I change my wlan broadcasting details with hostapd I get some output like this:

```
[ 6706.929857 ] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode
[ 6707.986991 ] br0: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
[ 6707.992803 ] br0: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
[ 6707.017990 ] br0: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
```

I have no idea what is causing this output, but it isn't hostapd since I use the `-f` argument for logging to a debug file. I even added `>/dev/null` at the end, and still the above output shows.

Where is this coming from and how do I make it silent?

Comment: It's coming from the kernel.  To silence these messages, but not others from the kernel, you'll need to dig into `syslog` or `rsyslog` depending upon your distro.

Comment: I'm using [minibian](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/) for my raspberry pi. Where would I start with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by running the following command on boot:

```
dmesg -n 1
```